# sqlite3.OperationalError - Trying to stop duplication of results

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I want this code to create one table and only print one list each time rather than printing multiple (the results from when it was run before). How what I fix this code so the WHERE NOT EXISTS code actually works.

The errors I have are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 33, in <module>
data_entry()
line 14, in data_entry
c.execute("INSERT INTO myTestTable VALUES('James', 45, 'Home') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTestTable WHERE name ='james' AND age =45 AND address ='school')") 
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

The code:

```
import sqlite3 

conn = sqlite3.connect('dbtest.db') 

c = conn.cursor() 

param = "School" 


def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTestTable(name TEXT, age REAL, address TEXT)') 

def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO myTestTable VALUES('James', 45, 'Home') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTestTable WHERE name ='james' AND age =45 AND address ='school')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO myTestTable VALUES('Jeff', 16, 'School') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTestTable WHERE name ='james' AND age =45 AND address ='school')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO myTestTable VALUES('Bob', 14, 'School') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTestTable WHERE name ='james' AND age =45 AND address ='school')")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO myTestTable VALUES('Jack', 15, 'School') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTestTable WHERE name ='james' AND age =45 AND address ='school')")
    conn.commit()

def query1():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM myTestTable WHERE address = ?",(param,)) 
    while True:
        row=c.fetchone()
        if row == None:
            break
        print(row)

    c.close()
    conn.close()

create_table()

data_entry()

query1()
```

Comment: An aside, I think your previous question (and its answer) has sent you down a bit of a wrong path here. You're hard-coding only the `james` entry so if you get your syntax to work, it won't stop you having duplicates of the other entries. Beyond your 3 test entries, this approach will become untenable.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite does not support `where` clauses on insert statements. I believe what you want to do will be to add a `unique` constraint to the table and use `insert or ignore`.

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTestTable(name TEXT, age REAL, address TEXT, UNIQUE(name, age, address))') 

c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO myTestTable VALUES('James', 45, 'Home')")
```

See below for details:

- https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html
- https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

This will also be a scalable solution, avoiding the problem @raganjosh points out. However, you will likely want to handle the duplication in way that notifies users.